# Is there any autostream extension for array in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

There is a way to stream array: `Arrays.stream(myArr)`, but it makes code a bit hard to read.
Is there any extensions, like Lombok, for avoiding and minimizing this to `myArr.stream()`, or even better to `myArr.filter(...)` or `myArr.forEach(...)`?

Comment: Arrays.stream is the correct mechanism to get a stream from an array.  The Arrays class is a helper class for work with arrays.  If you don't like this, avoid arrays and use the java Collections API.  java.util.Collection contains `stream()`

Comment: Not in Java.  Sure, you can some something else (like Lombok) ... but then you are not using real Java.

Comment: Readability is not in the eyes of the author, but a reader with fresh eyes.  `Arrays.stream()` actually has a meaning in Java, and the specification of `Arrays.stream()` is readily available (if not already known to the reader.)  Whereas monkey-patching a `stream()` method onto arrays via some extralinguistic mechanism (like Lombok) means that your reader has to read _your whole program_ before they can understand what this simple snippet of code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lombok to add an [extension method](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod.html). For example (untested):

```
@ExtensionMethod(java.util.Arrays.class)
public class Example {
    String[] myArr = {"A", "B", "C"};
    myArr.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

You can define your own `forEach()` extension method in the same way.

Comment: @BrianGoetz OP is clearly asking for an extralinguistic solution, which is exactly what I offered. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you think `Arrays.stream` is not readable. But the other alternative is `Stream.of`. For example `Stream.of(myarr)` Is that acceptable?